# Variable doesnt change within an object list

Tags: c++, list, class, draw

I'm making a little asteroids game using openGL and c++.
I ran into a problem which I will try to describe now.

I have a class for an asteroid that has variables and methods. It has a create method that sets current position of the asteroid and a draw method that it uses to change the position of the asteroid randomly.

When I try to use this asteroid in my main class, it works fine. It moves and does everything I wanted it to.

I then created a class for an Asteroid Generator that creates a list of asteroids and I also have a method that initialises the draw method on every element of the list. But when I run it, the asteroid doesn't move. I did a step through my code using visual studio and I found out that inside the draw method of the asteroid the value is changed correctly, but when the draw happens again the position is reset back to its original value, so it doesn't move. It could be something to do with c++ dumping memory after every method, so I believe Im messing up with pointers. I would appreciate any help you could give in spotting my error!

I added the header files and methods to show how Im using my asteroid generator.

AsteroidGen.h

```
#ifndef ASTEROIDGEN_H
#define ASTEROIDGEN_H

#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>    // for timeGetTime()
#include <mmsystem.h>   // ditto
#include <iostream>     // I/O
#include "model3DS.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include <glut.h>       // for gluPerspective & gluLookAt
#include <List>
#include "asteroid.h"
#include "position.h"

class AsteroidGen{
    public:
        std::list<Asteroid> listAsteroids;
        void AsteroidGen::generateAsteroid(int amount, int delet);
        void AsteroidGen::DrawAsteroids();
};

#endif // ASTEROIDGEN_H
```

AsteroidGen.cpp

```
#include "asteroidgen.h"

void AsteroidGen::generateAsteroid(int amount, int delet){
        if (delet == true)
            listAsteroids.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            Asteroid temp;
            temp.Create();
            listAsteroids.push_front(temp);
        }
}

void AsteroidGen::DrawAsteroids(){
    for each (Asteroid c in listAsteroids){
        c.Draw();  
    }
}
```

Asteroid.h

```
#ifndef ASTEROID_H
#define ASTEROID_H

#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>    // for timeGetTime()
#include <mmsystem.h>   // ditto
#include <iostream>     // I/O
#include "model3DS.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "position.h"
#include <glut.h>       // for gluPerspective & gluLookAt
#include <cmath>
#include "textureTGA.h"

class Asteroid{
    public:
    GLuint textureId;
        GLuint list;
        Position pos;
        float incX;
        float incY;
        float asteroidSpeed;
        float radio;
        float rotation;
        bool status;

        void Asteroid::GenSphere();
        void Asteroid::Reset();
        void Asteroid::Draw();
        void Asteroid::Create();
};

#endif // ASTEROID_H
```

Main.cpp

Initialised once

```
asteroidgen.generateAsteroid(1, false);
```

draw method every frame

```
asteroidgen.DrawAsteroids();
```

EDIT:

```
void Asteroid::Draw(){
    pos.z += asteroidSpeed;
    pos.y += incY;
    pos.x += incX;
    rotation += 1;

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);    
        glRotatef(rotation, 1, 1, 1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureId);
        glCallList(list);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: That code shouldn't compile, why do use the scope operator `::` inside the class?

Comment: What is the code inside Draw()? It's hard to help when we can't see how you're actually updating the position.

Comment: Sorry, I added the draw method. I didn't think that was the problem, but I guess it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `listAsteroids` holding Asteroids, instead of pointers to Asteroids. Fix it by changing `std::list<Asteroid> listAsteroids;` to `std::list<Asteroid*> listAsteroids;` and instead of `Asteroid temp;` do `Asteroid* temp = new Asteroid`.

Your actual problem is caused in the for loop. `for each (Asteroid c in listAsteroids)` here you get a copy-by-value of every one of your Asteroid instances as `Asteroid c`, which then gets changed, and doesn't change the actual instance. Again use `Asteroid* c` here, so you get a pointer to the **actual** instance.

This way your list contains pointers to the actual instances of Asteroids, rather than ever copying the instances by value (which causes those temporary changes to a temporary object)

On top of fixing your problem, this saves both time and resources; if you ever use the list for example as a parameter in a function, it's much faster to copy the pointers rather than values. Just remember to use `->` instead of `.`

Comment: That works perfectly! I knew it was a problem with pointers. I get really confused using them. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, I know how frustrating pointers and references can be for a newcomer -- They were the hardest part in C++ for me to learn so far. But keep on coding, you'll get used to them eventually!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it is possible that your copy constructor of your Astroid class does not work correctly with OpenGL? I notice that in the generate method, you create a new astroid on the stack, call the Create() function and then push it on the list. At that point in time, the list has a copy of that created astroid and not that exact one called temp. I would personally create an astroid on the heap, and then make the list a list of pointers to astroids. As long as you remember to do all the proper memory clean up, that might help. Let me know if this was even close!

Comment: Yes I was doing it a bit strange way, but I wasn't sure how to do it any other way :( I am quite bad with pointers. IT does create the randomly generated asteroids in random positions. They just dont move because the position gets reset every Draw() call.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with that "for each" loop; it appears to be iterating the list by value, so taking a copy of each Asteroid in the list which then gets modified in its Draw method, but those modifications are lost because it's only a copy.

I'm not fully sure though because that's non-standard syntax; as far as I can see it's some weird Visual C++ extension. The standard way of writing that is:

```
for (Asteroid& asteroid : listAsteroids) {
    asteroid.Draw();
}
```

And because that's a reference, the changes should stick.

Comment: This syntax doesn't seem to be recognised.

Comment: I guess your version of Visual C++ doesn't support C++0x?